# Flex chart gradient fill not a smooth transition

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a bar chart whose columns I'd like to apply a linear gradient fill to via the setStyle method. In the method I'm using to configure the colors, the following code sets the gradient:

```
public function configureColor(series:Series):void {
    var lg:LinearGradient = GradientUtil.getLinearGradient([color1, color2], 0.8, 45);
    series.setStyle("fill", lg);
  ...
}
```

The getLinearGradient method:

```
public function getLinearGradient(colors:Array, alpha:Number, angle:Number = 0.0):LinearGradient {
    var lg:LinearGradient = new LinearGradient();
    lg.angle = angle;
    var entries:Array = []
    for each (var color:uint in colors) {
        entries.push(new GradientEntry(color, NaN, alpha));
    }
    lg.entries = entries;
    return lg;
}
```

For some reason, the gradients that I get on the columns are "choppy". The transition from one color to the next occurs in a very small section of the column, rather than a smooth transition from the top to the bottom of the bar. How can I get it so that it does end up being a smooth transition?

Edit: Example of what the issue I'm having looks like 
 [image]

Comment: You might want include a screen shot so we can better understand what is happening. Have you tried changing the angle of your gradient?

Comment: Gone ahead and added an image (http://i.imgur.com/7H3Fx.png). I have tried changing the angle but the same issue happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the `LinearGradient` class. My initial assumption was that it was the `BoxItemRenderer` that draws the fill in the chart. But looking there pointed me at the gradient's `begin()` method which the renderer uses to begin the fill.

The problem is perhaps a special case, that is noticeable when using non-90 degree angles on a rectangle who's width to height ratio is large. You can recreate this problem with a simple rect:

```
<s:Rect width="200" height="40">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="45">
            <s:GradientEntry color="#ff0000"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="#0000ff"/>
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

My hacky solution was to extend `LinearGradient` and override its `begin()` method. I copied the original code, and commented out a few lines that made it determine the wrong width. I tested that w/various angles and it seems to render OK.

Admittedly, I don't understand the purpose of the lines I commented out, and there is probably a valid use case.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.GradientType;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.graphics.LinearGradient;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class CustomGradient extends LinearGradient
    {
        private static var commonMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

        public function CustomGradient()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function begin(target:Graphics, targetBounds:Rectangle, targetOrigin:Point):void
        {
            commonMatrix.identity();

            if (!compoundTransform)
            {
                var tx:Number = x;
                var ty:Number = y;
                var length:Number = scaleX;

                if (isNaN(length))
                {
                    // Figure out the two sides
                    if (rotation % 90 != 0)
                    {           
//                      // Normalize angles with absolute value > 360 
//                      var normalizedAngle:Number = rotation % 360;
//                      // Normalize negative angles
//                      if (normalizedAngle < 0)
//                          normalizedAngle += 360;
//                      
//                      // Angles wrap at 180
//                      normalizedAngle %= 180;
//                      
//                      // Angles > 90 get mirrored
//                      if (normalizedAngle > 90)
//                          normalizedAngle = 180 - normalizedAngle;
//                      
//                      var side:Number = targetBounds.width;
//                      // Get the hypotenuse of the largest triangle that can fit in the bounds
//                      var hypotenuse:Number = Math.sqrt(targetBounds.width * targetBounds.width + targetBounds.height * targetBounds.height);
//                      // Get the angle of that largest triangle
//                      var hypotenuseAngle:Number =  Math.acos(targetBounds.width / hypotenuse) * 180 / Math.PI;
//                      
//                      // If the angle is larger than the hypotenuse angle, then use the height 
//                      // as the adjacent side of the triangle
//                      if (normalizedAngle > hypotenuseAngle)
//                      {
//                          normalizedAngle = 90 - normalizedAngle;
//                          side = targetBounds.height;
//                      }
//                      
//                      // Solve for the hypotenuse given an adjacent side and an angle. 
//                      length = side / Math.cos(normalizedAngle / 180 * Math.PI);
                        length=Math.max(targetBounds.width, targetBounds.height);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // Use either width or height based on the rotation
                        length = (rotation % 180) == 0 ? targetBounds.width : targetBounds.height;
                    }
                }

                // If only x or y is defined, force the other to be set to 0
                if (!isNaN(tx) && isNaN(ty))
                    ty = 0;
                else if (isNaN(tx) && !isNaN(ty))
                    tx = 0;

                // If x and y are specified, then move the gradient so that the
                // top left corner is at 0,0
                if (!isNaN(tx) && !isNaN(ty))
                    commonMatrix.translate(GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2, GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2); // 1638.4 / 2

                // Force the length to a absolute minimum of 2. Values of 0, 1, or -1 have undesired behavior   
                if (length >= 0 && length < 2)
                    length = 2;
                else if (length < 0 && length > -2)
                    length = -2;

                // Scale the gradient in the x direction. The natural size is 1638.4px. No need
                // to scale the y direction because it is infinite
                commonMatrix.scale (length / GRADIENT_DIMENSION, 1 / GRADIENT_DIMENSION);

                commonMatrix.rotate (!isNaN(_angle) ? _angle : rotationInRadians);
                if (isNaN(tx))
                    tx = targetBounds.left + targetBounds.width / 2;
                else
                    tx += targetOrigin.x;
                if (isNaN(ty))
                    ty = targetBounds.top + targetBounds.height / 2;
                else
                    ty += targetOrigin.y;
                commonMatrix.translate(tx, ty); 
            }
            else
            {
                commonMatrix.translate(GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2, GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2);
                commonMatrix.scale(1 / GRADIENT_DIMENSION, 1 / GRADIENT_DIMENSION);
                commonMatrix.concat(compoundTransform.matrix);
                commonMatrix.translate(targetOrigin.x, targetOrigin.y);
            }            

            target.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios,
                commonMatrix, spreadMethod, interpolationMethod);   
        }
    }
}
```

**[Edit]** Commented out the entire if statement and use the max dimension for the `length` instead. Original hack  only commented out the `if (normalizedAngle > hypotenuseAngle)` clause. Probably still buggy, but addresses both problem cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help - as it turns on this does seem to provide a solution to the problem I brought up, but it breaks the opposite scenario, where the width to height ratio is reversed (i.e. there are two buggy scenarios here: one where the height to width ratio is really big and one where the width to height ratio is really big). I will keep working on possibly finding a fix for both issues. Thanks!

Comment: Had another go at it, even did a trigonometry refresh. But only came up with this new hack that handles the other case too. I'm not sure that random angles will work properly (they seem to) but usual ones do. If you find a good solution, please edit or share a new answer!